# How do I show the the expanded polymer elements in Dartium?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Is there a way to show in Dartium/Chrome the expanded DOM after a PolymerElement gets expanded? When I go to "Inspect Element" in Dartium, I can find the custom element, but it doesn't expand out. It doesn't seem to be binding to a property correctly (or at least how I think it should), and I would at least like to get a snapshot of what value it is pulling out.

Thanks,

-D

Comment: I guess nobody saw your question because most people monitor only the dart tag. Just add it on all Dart related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Show Shadow DOM` in the settings of the developer tools.[image]